# Access my data after a useFetch into serverSupabaseClient

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, supabase

I'm using nuxt 3 with the [supabase module](http://supabase.nuxtjs.org/usage/services/serversupabaseclient)

I have a component "AddIngredients.vue", I try to make an api call using

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
const { data } = await useFetch("/api/getAlimentaryProducts")
console.log(data.value.data.length)
</script>
```

I perfectly got what I wanted inside /api/getAlimentaryProducts.ts

```
import { serverSupabaseClient } from "#supabase/server"

export default eventHandler(async (event) => {
  const supabase = await serverSupabaseClient(event)

  const { data, error } = await supabase.from("alimentary_products").select("id, name")

  return { data, error }
})
```

But back to my component, I have to write this to get my data:

```js
console.log(data.value.data.length)
```

My data var is a RefImpl type
[image: what I receive as data]

Is there a better way to get my data, rather than write this ugly `data.value.data.length`?

Comment: No better way per-se, but you can store it in a variable and make it more concise indeed. This is the right way to go. Consider [a composable](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables.html) too if you really want it shorter.

Answer (score 1):

Based on luckygem's answer

```js
const { data: { value: { data: alimentaryProduct } } } = await useFetch("/api/getAlimentaryProducts")
```

Comment: No point in posting a copy of the answer. Just accept his if that solves your issue.

Comment: @kissu In general, yes, but in this case luckygem seems to be spamming ChatGPT answers so I'd caution against encouraging them further. Also, this is different than that answer, which neglected the `value` property.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood correctly you want something like that

```
import { serverSupabaseClient } from "#supabase/server"

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const supabase = await serverSupabaseClient(event)

  const { data, error } = await supabase.from("alimentary_products").select("id, name")

  return { getAlimentaryProducts:data, error }
})
```

return in this format after that you can use like in the component

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const { data } = await useFetch("/api/getAlimentaryProducts")
</script>
<template>
   {{data.getAlimentaryProducts.length}}
</template>
```

Answer (score -1):

To make this code more concise and to avoid using data.value.data.length, you can destructure the data object directly in your setup script as shown below:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { useFetch } from '@nuxt/http'
const { data } = useFetch("/api/getAlimentaryProducts")
const { data: alimentaryProducts } = data

console.log(alimentaryProducts.length)
</script>
```

By destructuring the data object and renaming it to alimentaryProducts, you can access the length directly as alimentaryProducts.length, which can make your code cleaner and more readable.

Comment: You could actually do it directly like `const { data: { alimentaryProducts } } = useFetch("/api/getAlimentaryProducts")` if I'm not mistaken (kinda bypassing the ref itself?).

Comment: Yes, that is also possible.

<script setup lang="ts">
import { useFetch } from '@nuxt/http'
const { data: { alimentaryProducts } } = useFetch("/api/getAlimentaryProducts")

console.log(alimentaryProducts.length)
</script>